# Dealing with pointer arithmetic of a void data type

Tags: c, mpi

I know that in C arithmetic of void pointers is not allowed. However I must find a solution to deal with this issue.

I have a function that sends the first half of an array to rank 0 and the second half to rank 1:

```
void send_expand_multiple(void * data, MPI_Datatype datatype, int size) {
    int my_rank, comm_size, intercomm_size, localSize, factor, dst, iniPart, iniPartBytes, i;
    int datatype_size;
    MPI_Type_size(datatype, &datatype_size);

    int local_size = size / 2;

    //Sending the first half
    MPI_Send(data, local_size, datatype, dst, 0, comm);

    //Sending the second half
    int iniPart = local_size;
    int iniPartBytes = iniPart * datatype_size;
    MPI_Send(((char *) data) + iniPartBytes, local_size, datatype, dst, 1, comm);
}
```

My solution is based on the principle of "serializing". For the first half, there is no problem, but for the second I have parsed the buffer and moved the pointer **iniPartBytes** by adding that value.

Finally, the count and the datatype configure the MPI_Send in order to send **local_size** elements of **datatype** type.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: `int local_size = size / 2;` can loose 1 byte in case of odd value

Comment: This is a simplification of the code, so let's assume that it cannot be odd. Thank you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right. My fault, sorry. Now is edited.

Comment: You did state a problem so it is OT on SO. You can have more luck on [codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LPs that is what I though, but a user from there, redirected me...

Comment: siserte That's kind of funny. It's like virtual tennis on stackexchange sites. Anyway, I think what LPs was getting at was what specifically is your problem? Is it not compiling? Is it compiling but not producing the intended output? Also, note that C doesn't require that different pointer types be the same size, though in practice on many (probably most modern) systems this is the case.

Comment: @mgarey It is not a problem but an asking for advice. I'm not sure if my solution is appropriate for distributing a library.

Comment: An object may have a size in the range of type `size_t`.  Using `int size` may be insufficient.

Comment: @chux `int size` is unfortunately sufficient (because that's what MPI uses). `int iniPartBytes` however is not.

Comment: "Is my approach correct?" I see that code does not divide the 2 parts on `datatype_size` boundaries as a potential problem.

Comment: Please clarify: Is `int size` the byte size of array or the count of the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @chux **size** is the number of elements of **data**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two areas I see trouble:

Pointer calculation  `iniPart * datatype_size` may overflow.  Suggest use C99   pointer math.

`size` may be odd - although OP dismisses this, a fix is easy.

```
void send_expand_multiple(const void * data, MPI_Datatype datatype, int element_count) {
    int dst = tbd();
    MPI_Comm comm = tbd();

    int datatype_size;
    MPI_Type_size(datatype, &datatype_size);
    int first_half_count = element_count / 2;
    int second_half_count = element_count  - first_half_count;

    //Sending the first half
    MPI_Send(data, first_half_count, datatype, dst, 0, comm);

    //Sending the second half
    const char (*first_half)[first_half_count][datatype_size] = data;
    MPI_Send(first_half + 1, second_half_count, datatype, dst, 1, comm);

    // or
    const char (*first_half)[datatype_size] = data;
    MPI_Send(first_half + first_half_count, second_half_count, datatype, dst, 1, comm);
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "OP"?

Comment: @siserte [OP](https://www.internetslang.com/OP-meaning-definition.asp) is the original poster, siserte (you), in this case.